# Build Error while debugging the Xamaron.iOS application through iPhone

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

My application is build and working successfully on Simulator. However, building the application while connecting the device(iPad) and it throws error as **Could not resolve the host IPs for WiFi debugger settings**

Task "DetectDebugNetworkConfiguration" .... Build Failed.

May I know why it behaves in such way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Xamarin [Troubleshooting Docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/troubleshooting/mtouch-errors/#MT7001_Could_not_resolve_host_IPs_for_WiFi_debugger_settings.) can put you in the right direction.

Anyhow, it doesn't answer your question.

I'm assuming you are using an Apple device for development.
The debugger relies on Apple's proprietary 'Bonjour' service.

You need to make sure it's up and running. 
This can easily be done by enabling 'File Sharing'. 
Just go to **System Preferences < Sharing**  and enable '**File Sharing**'